MRI_3D-Planes illustration in display
Since I tend to work on MRI, I can perform preprocessing and processing steps related to MRI and fMRI images on standard images using SPM/FSL soft wares, and there is no problem.
The only problem I am dealing with right now is the problem related to the input data from the ADNI website, which does not allow the SPM software to process correctly.

After downloading  and extracting the sMRI data from ADNI, the 3 orientation of image(i.e: sagittal,Axial and coronal view) are in 3 sub-folders separately and I couldn't observe the 3 views together in display ( in SPM12 or FSL).

2)I couldn't run the  the metadata file (jsp and xml format)and using all the  information by text file information. which has all the comprehensive information of an image such as TR ,number of slices and so on ,which is necessary for entering into the software and preprocessing.)
I also corresponded with ADNI site experts, but they suggested the same normal search and advanced search methods on the website.
Therefore, I respectfully ask you  if possible, to suggest practical solutions to solve these challenges.
Thanks a lot
Sincerely,
I did download the data from, ADNI dataset and seems that all the images are similar to each other and I had problems as I mentioned above.

The Matlab functions are usually very good at importing.  You can write Matlab code and then convert to a dll to use with other applications.
